# How to get shift+mousescroll event in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox

I have 200 photos in my webpage, which has browser scroll and selection for that photos, i implemented shift selection functionality for photo selection. But i have issue in firefox that, when i select photo and press shift key and scroll down mouse the browser is navigating back and forth, Is there any practice to capture both shift + scroll event in firefox.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Try this, should work in both Chrome and Firefox.

```
$(document).on('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function(event) {
  if (event.shiftKey) {
    // do something.
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You must return false in your event handler.

```
 $(document).bind('mousewheel', function (event) {
     // do your stuff
     return false;
   });
```